# Is there a way to check if the user is streaming and display it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I've tried to make a bot that checks if certain user is streaming but for some reason it doesn't go further than check 3.

```js
client.on("presenceUpdate", (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
    if(newPresence.user.id === config.LORD_ID) {
        console.log("Check 2 passed")
    if(newPresence.guild.id === config.STRATZ_SERVER_ID) {
        console.log("Check 3 passed")
    if (!newPresence.activities) return false;
    newPresence.activities.forEach(activity => {
        if (activity.type == "STREAMING") {
            console.log("Check 4 passed")
            if (canNotifyStreaming) {
                console.log("Check 5 passed")
                if(activity.url.startsWith("www.youtube.com")) {
                    console.log("Final check passed")
                    itsYOUTUBESTREAMTIME();
                    canNotifyStreaming = false;
                    setTimeout(() => { canNotifyStreaming = true; }, 86400000);
                } else if(activity.url.startsWith("www.twitch.tv")) {
                    console.log("Final check for twitch passed")
                    itsSTREAMTIME();
                    canNotifyStreaming = false;
                    setTimeout(() => { canNotifyStreaming = true; }, 86400000);
                }
            }
        };
    });
   }
 }
});
```

Is there a reason that the code refuses to go further than check 3?

Note: sorry if the problem is stupid, i've only coded with discord.js and node.js in general only for 3 months

Comment: When you return, it stops execution of the remainder of the function. Probably means newPresence.activites is falsey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if (!newPresence.activities) return false;`
This stop the code, try:

```js
    if (newPresence.activities) {
        newPresence.activities.forEach(activity => {
        // ...
    }
```

Comment: thanks it worked, but the final check won't go through.